# Will the meaning change if I change "when-clause"?

Tags: tense, past-tense, clauses, subordinate-clauses

do these sentences have different meanings?

**When she was back, I decided to do my homework.**(Can this one have two meanings?)

**I decided to do my homework when she was back.**(Can this one have two meanings?)

***When she was back, I was going to do my homework.***

***I was going to do my homework when she was back.***

Comment: You probably mean "when she returned".  Also, "when she *came* back" is fine.

Comment: Andrew made some good points in his answer. This remains as a comment: putting when at the beginning of either clause makes it marginal to the whole story (subordination). Sometimes this becomes really clear. Read this example for instance; doesn't it sound alittle off? _I came back from work when I saw a 10-foot cobra in my bed_. Now read this: _When I came back from work, I saw a 10-foot cobra in my bed_ or _after coming back from work, I saw a 10-foot cobra in my bed. **Source**:  _Writing with Confidence_.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean "when she returned" (since "when she was back" is not natural English):

> When she returned, I decided to do my homework

She came back, and then I made the decision to do my homework.

> I decided to do my homework when she returned

I decided *in advance* to do my homework at the time when she returned.  Although it can also mean that you decided at the moment she came back, this would not be my initial interpretation.

> When she returned, I was going to do my homework

At the time she returned I intended to do my homework (but then something happened).

> I was going to do my homework when she returned.

Either I had planned to do my homework at the time she came back (but then something happened), or her returning *interrupted* my intention to do my homework.

Comment: Thanks for your help!!!But can the second one mean" I decided to do homework at the time she returned"?

Comment: Yes, as I said, but without additional context and/or punctuation, it wouldn't be my first thought.

Comment: Shouldn't the second one be **"I decided to do my homework when she returns"** *(upon her return)* to mean **"I decided in advance to do my homework at the time when she returned."** *(upon her return)*

Comment: The 4th sentence gets clearer if you add **"suddenly"** after **"when"**. *"I was going to do my homework when suddenly she returned."*

Comment: @SovereignSun  "I decided to do my homework when she returned" means both actions happened in the past.  Unless it is a direct quote, eg "I told her, 'I will do my homework when you return'" you would back-shift the verb as with reported speech.